# Puppeteer setCacheEnabled not working when reusing window/page

Tags: puppeteer

I have this code to intercept and modify javascript files:

```
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  await page.setCacheEnabled(false);

  page.on('request', async (request) => {
    if (request.url().includes(".js")) {
```

It responds only to JS that is requested from 3rd party servers, but for any local js it serves the cache.

I am trying to reuse the same chromium window/page. I have tried checking "Disable cache" in dev tools as well.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what is the question here?

Comment: Please try args:['--disable-cache']

Comment: Also you need to set ignoreDefaultArgs: true in config